# Can we change the HTML DOM object in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
from htmldom import htmldom
dom = htmldom.HtmlDom("URL")
dom = dom.createDom()
plist = dom.find("div[id=AllProductsMenu]")
plist1 = plist.find('li')
p_links = plist1.find('a')
#print(plist.html())
#print(dom)
for link in p_links:
  Link = link.attr("href")
  LinktoProduct = Link.replace('/Cls_','URL')
  LinktoProduct1 = LinktoProduct.replace('/Promotion/', 'URL')
  #print(LinktoProduct1)
  dom = htmldom.HtmlDom(LinktoProduct1)
  #print(LinktoProduct1.html())
  #div = dom.find("div")
  SingleProduct = dom.find("div[id=bodycontent]")
  print(SingleProduct.html())
  #SingleProduct = dom.find("ul[class=thumbnails four-column clearfix]")
  imagelist = SingleProduct.find('li')
  imagelist1 = imagelist.find('a')
  for imagelink in imagelist1:
      ImgLink = imagelink.attr("href")
      print(ImgLink)
```

In the above code i want to change the DOM object in the following for loop but i am not able to do that can you help me...

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: nothing no error

Comment: Then please 1. remove the commented-out code to make your code more readable, and 2. describe what you would expect and what you see happening instead.

Comment: You can change an in memory python object, yes, but you cannot manipulate the HTML content of the page itself